# Parallax on Mobile Not Adjusting

Tags: jquery, css, bootstrap-4, parallax

I setup a simple set of parallax sections on my homepage, and on my desktop it works perfectly, even when the screen is shrunk to mobile size. However, when viewed on an ios device, the image does not scale properly. The CSS in inline for now, and the draft can be found [here](https://c0092.paas1.tx.modxcloud.com/). Thanks for any help you can provide.

CSS

```
.parallax {
    height:350px;
}
section.module.parallax-1 {
  background-image: url("https://c0092.paas1.tx.modxcloud.com/assets/img/parallax/parallax_1.jpg");
  background-position: 50% 0;
  background-repeat: repeat;
  background-attachment: fixed;
  background-size: cover;
  /* background-color: rgba(0,123,255,0.4); */
  background-blend-mode: screen;
  }
section.module.parallax-2 {
  background-image: url("https://c0092.paas1.tx.modxcloud.com/assets/img/parallax/parallax_2.jpg");
  background-position: 50% 0;
  background-repeat: repeat;
  background-attachment: fixed;
  background-size: cover;
  /* background-color: rgba(0,123,255,0.4); */
  background-blend-mode: screen;
}
section.module.parallax-3 {
  background-image: url("https://c0092.paas1.tx.modxcloud.com/assets/img/parallax/parallax_3.jpg");
  background-position: 50% 0 !important;
  background-repeat: repeat;
  background-attachment: fixed;
  background-size: cover;
  /* background-color: rgba(0,123,255,0.4); */
  background-blend-mode: screen;
}
  .parallax-container h2 span {
      font-size:100px!important;
      /* color:#f7971e; */
      color:#ffffff;
      position: absolute;
      margin-top:100px;
      text-shadow:1px 1px 10px #000, 1px 1px 10px #000;
  }
```

HTML

```
<section class="module parallax parallax-1" data-type="background" data-speed="10">
                    <div class="parallax-container">
                        <h2 class="mx-auto d-flex justify-content-center"><span>Fitness</span></h2></span>
                    </div>
                </section>
```

JS

```
//parallax js
$(document).ready(function(){
  var $window = $(window);
    $('section[data-type="background"]').each(function(){
        var $bgobj = $(this); // assigning the object

        $(window).scroll(function() {
            var yPos = -($window.scrollTop() / $bgobj.data('speed')); 

            // Put together our final background position
            var coords = '50% '+ yPos + 'px';

            // Move the background
            $bgobj.css({ backgroundPosition: coords });
        }); 
    });    
});
```